# Splitting input into buckets - Perl

Tags: perl

I know how to do this the long winded way, but I am wondering if there is a simple way to split a series of numbers into buckets.

I have a series of data that associates two numbers together:

Frequency Value

I want to break up the values into subsections of frequency and then get the mean and standard deviation of the members of each span of 0.05 of the frequency results.

So what I want is a series of arrays holding the values associated to the frequencies.

My long winded approach is

```
%results = ();
$key = int( ( $frequency * 100 ) / 20 );
if ( !exists( $results{$key} ) ) {
    @temp = ($value);
    $results{$key} = @temp;
} else {
    $results{$key} = push( $results{$key}, $value );
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: It would probably be more informative if you edited your question to include where you're getting `$frequency` and `$value` from -- e.g. are they in arrays? Some complicated data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to check if things exist when you're trying to fetch data from a hash table. You don't need to do it when adding data to the table.
Also, you don't need to put temporary names on arrays. You can make anonymous arrays by putting [ ] around a list of numbers. You can also make anonymous hashes using { }, but that doesn't directly relate to this problem.

```
my %results;    #will store data like $results{$frequency} = [list of values]
# storing data:
my $key = int( ( $frequency * 100 ) / 20 );
push @{$results{$frequency}}, $value;           #the @{ } means interpret $results{$frequency} as an array
# fetching data, here is where you check if things exist, sometimes
foreach (keys %results) {
    print "For $_ frequency...\n";
    print "The values are: @{$results{$_}}\n\n";    #if you don't include @{ }, it will say ARRAYREF(0xsdfasdf)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you actually want a Hash of Arrays.

Therefore you need to just [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html):

```
push @{ $results{$key} }, $value;
```

For more info on such concepts, check out [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).